# Show that if X is compact and Y is Lindelöf, then then X×Y is Lindelöf.

Tags: general-topology, lindelof-spaces

Here is my attempt:

''Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a open cover for $X\times Y$. Let $y$ in $Y$, since $X \times {y} \cong X$, then $X \times {y}$ is compact. Then, there is finite subcover $\mathcal{G}_{y}=\{G_{y,1},G_{y,2}, \dots, G_{y,n}\}$ of $\mathcal{G}$ such that $$X \times {y}=\bigcup \mathcal{G}_{y} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}G_{y,i}. $$
Now $\{\pi_{2}(\mathcal{\bigcup G}_{y}) \ |\ y \in Y\}$ (where $\pi_{2}:X\times Y \to Y$ is projection) is a open cover of $Y$. Since $Y$ is Lindelöf, there is countable subcover of $\{\pi_{2}(\mathcal{\bigcup G}_{y}) \ |\ y \in Y\}$, say $\{\pi_{2}(\mathcal{\bigcup G}_{y_{i}}) \ |\ i \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Thus, $\{\bigcup \mathcal{G}_{y_{i}} \ | \ i\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is countable subcover of $\mathcal{G}$. Hence, $X\times Y$ is Lindelöf.''

Is it true? If it is true, why can't similar proof be done for Tychonoff's theorem?

Comment: What did finding the finite subcover of $X \times y$ give you?

Comment: @BrianMoehring i use that subcover to form a open cover of $Y$.

Comment: You never use it's a _finite_ subcover essentially anywhere, though, and as a result, the ending collection may not cover $X\times Y$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Could you tell me exactly where i am wrong?

Comment: Instead of considering the open cover of $Y$ you used, try using $\{\bigcap\pi_2(\mathcal{G}_y) : y \in Y\}$, for the appropriate definition of $\pi_2(\mathcal{G}_y)$.  Do you see how finiteness of $\mathcal{G}_y$ is used?  Also, do you see where the axiom of choice is used?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is faulty.  From$$
 \pi_2\left(\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}\mathcal G_{y_i}\right)= Y
$$
we cannot conclude
$$
\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N}\mathcal G_{y_i} = X \times Y .
$$

---

A simple example.  Let $X \times Y$ be the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ shown in gray.
Let $A$ be a triangle shown in yellow.
Let $B$ be a square shown in blue.
Let $C$ be a triangle shown in green.
Let $D$ be a square shown in red.
Suppose we have chosen (among others): $\mathcal G_0 = \{A,B\}$ which covers $X \times \{0\}$; and $\mathcal G_1 = \{C,D\}$ which covers $X \times \{1\}$.  [Of course we have also chosen $\mathcal G_y$ for $0<y<1$, which we will not need below.]

[image: A]

Then we get (approximately) $\pi_2(\bigcup \mathcal G_0) = [0,9/10)$ and $\pi_2(\bigcup \mathcal G_1) = (1/10,1]$.  So these two sets cover $Y$.  [That's why  we don't need the other $\mathcal G_y$.]
But $\bigcup \mathcal G_0 \cup \bigcup \mathcal G_1$, shown below, is **not** $X \times Y$.  There is still some gray showing.

[image: B]

Comment: It is awesome example, i understand now, Thanks